# CodeIgniter Noob - How does the index.php file work?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my `views` directory:

```
-    views/
    -    home.php
    -    contact.php
    -    assets/
        -    css/
            -    main.css
```

config.php: (changing this doesn't seem to do anything)

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
```

When I request `www.example.com/index.php`, the default page (i.e. home.php) loads and all of the assets work. However, when I request `www.example.com/index.php/welcome` or `www.example.com/index.php/welcome/index`, the page loads but the assets don't work. The same also happens if I try to load the page from a link from the home page.

I have no idea what index.php is for. I want to be able to just request `www.example.com/welcome/index` which will call the `welcome.php` controller and call the `index` method. `application/index.php` looks pretty important for everything to work, do I haven't deleted it, but I don't really want it. What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show me code for home.php and contact.php .. ?

Comment: Can you check the assets link when they are not accessible? debugging this way may can solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking 3 different questions here.

Firstly index.php is the main entry point for your codeigniter app. It's very important as all of your routes will go through the index. The reason you can change it in the config is so you can rename it to something other than index.php if your setup requires it

Secondly, just guessing here but I think your assets are being loaded using a relative path; prefix all of your assets with base_url(); e.g 
    `<?=base_url();?>assets/css/style.css`

Thirdly, you'll need a htaccess file to hide the index.php (to give you www.example.com/welcome), or the equivalent if you're not using an apache server, which will look like the below (taken from http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Ok I tried this: `<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/views/assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` but it didn't work. I still get a 404 page not found error for the css request. Btw my `config.php` is like this: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com:666/';`

Comment: The CI documentation now resides @ http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html since Ellislab have given the project to BCIT

Comment: Move your assets to the root of the project. Views should be fore view files only.

Comment: Is this a must? Since I am only using the stylesheets, JS and images in the views, it only makes sense to have them within the view folder.

Comment: The application folders shouldn't have public access. Your webroot is publis so putting your assets folder here is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mode Rewriting on your server LAMP/WAMP and add a .htaccess file with following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

after doing above process you can use your urls without index.php i.e like `www.example.com/welcome/index` as well as your assets directory `www.example.com/assets`

Answer (score 0):

Before all learn How MVC framework will work,

**`www.example.com/controller/function`**

If you call `www.example.com` , then default `controller` will load. You can change this in `config.php`

Inside the function you can call `view` ( your actual html viewable scripts ). follow the user guide from https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide

by default codeignitor url will be like `www.example.com/index.php/controller/function`

index.php can be removed using `.htaccess`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understand that, but the problem is that the assets don't work when I request the page with the controller/function in the URL. The assets only work when I request `www.example.com` or `www.example.com/index.php`.